# Summation with a variable in lower limit and upper limit (For convolution)

Tags: summation, convolution

I am currently trying to solve a convolution problem **analytically**

For the discrete-time input signal x(n) and the step response h(n)

$$ 
  x(n) = \left.
  \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{for } 0 \leq n \leq 9 \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  \right\}
$$

$$ 
  h(n) = \left.
  \begin{cases}
    0.9^{n}, & \text{for } n \geq 0 \\
    0, & \text{otherwsie}
  \end{cases}
  \right\}
$$

The convolution for y(n) is as follows:
$$
y(n) =  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h(k) x(n-k)
$$

I divided the problem into 3 cases

Case 1: $ n < 0 $. There would be no overlap between h(k) and x(n-k) so y(n) = 0

Case 2: $ 0 \leq n \leq 9 $. I resolved it using the geometric series identity.
$$
y(n) =  \sum_{k=0}^{n} 0.9^{k} = \frac{1-0.9^{n+1}}{1-0.9}
$$
Case 3: $ n \geq 9 $.
$$
y(n) =  \sum_{k=n-9}^{n} 0.9^{k}
$$

Now I am stuck in resolving this summation $ y(n) =  \sum_{k=n-9}^{n} 0.9^{k} $. I know that this summation will always have 9 terms, but what identity can I use to get an analytical expression for this convolution?

I saw a solution once for it that resolves it as  $ y(n) =  0.9^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{9} 0.9^{-k} $. However, I am not sure if this is correct and I don't know how it got to that shape.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a look at this post: [Non-infinite geometric sum; does not start at 0 or 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634725/non-infinite-geometric-sum-does-not-start-at-0-or-1)

I found the answer!

The sum
$$
y(n) =  \sum_{k=n-9}^{n} 0.9^{k}
$$

can be expressed as
$$
y(n) =  \sum_{k=n-9}^{n} 0.9^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 0.9^{k} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-9} 0.9^{k}
$$

which then can be resolved as
$$
y(n) =  \frac{1 - 0.9^{n+1}}{1 - 0.9} - \frac{1-0.9^{n}}{1-0.9} = \frac{-0.9^{n+1}+0.9^{n}}{0.1}
$$